# Get the hard disk information using Perl

Tags: windows, perl

I want to use the perl to check the hard disk space on **Windows**, is there any way to do it?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see [Win32::DriveInfo](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::DriveInfo)

```
($SectorsPerCluster, $BytesPerSector, $NumberOfFreeClusters, 
$TotalNumberOfClusters, $FreeBytesAvailableToCaller, $TotalNumberOfBytes, $TotalNumberOfFreeBytes) =  Win32::DriveInfo::DriveSpace( drive );

   $SectorsPerCluster          - number of sectors per cluster.
   $BytesPerSector             - number of bytes per sector.
   $NumberOfFreeClusters       - total number of free clusters on the disk.
   $TotalNumberOfClusters      - total number of clusters on the disk.
   $FreeBytesAvailableToCaller - total number of free bytes on the disk that
                                 are available to the user associated with the
                                 calling thread, b.
   $TotalNumberOfBytes         - total number of bytes on the disk, b.
   $TotalNumberOfFreeBytes     - total number of free bytes on the disk, b.
```

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time, a portable solutions such as [`Filesys::DfPortable`](http://p3rl.org/Filesys::DfPortable) is the better choice. Recognise the opportunity to be [virtuously lazy](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/index.cgi?laziness).

Answer (score 1):

[Win32 Drive Info](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-DriveInfo/DriveInfo.pm) should do the trick.
I guess your are looking for

> $TotalNumberOfFreeBytes

Answer (score 0):

Another way to query the system state is to query the [Windows Management Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx) using [DBD::WMI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-WMI/lib/DBD/WMI.pm).

The following query should give you the basic info about disk space:

```
Select DeviceID,Size,FreeSpace from Win32_LogicalDisk
```