# How to find disk space using perl in Windows machine?

Tags: perl

I need to get the free disk space, total disk space in windows machine using perl.

For an example,

```
use strict;
my $curr_drive="c:\";
```

From the above code, I want to get the c:\ drive free space and total space.
I have tried with Filesys::DiskSpace module. But I dont how to proceed the module for windows.
Please share your solutions.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the hard disk information using Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519575/get-the-hard-disk-information-using-perl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module [Filesys::DiskSpace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys%3a%3aDiskSpace) is unsupported on Windows. You have to use [Win32::DriveInfo](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aDriveInfo).

Try the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::DriveInfo;

my (undef, undef, undef, undef, undef, $total, $free) =
    Win32::DriveInfo::DriveSpace('c');
```

Comment: As stated in [Get the hard disk information using Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519575/get-the-hard-disk-information-using-perl), the `Filesys::DfPortable;` module should be preferred as being a portable solution (which supports Windows).

Answer (score 2):

I believe CPAN has your answer:
[DriveInfo](http://search.cpan.org/~mblaz/Win32-DriveInfo-0.06/DriveInfo.pm)